# EIGRP : Feasibility Condition not satisfied

Tags: cisco, routing, eigrp

What happen if the Feasibility Condition not satisfied and we can not pick a feasible successor?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

A feasible successor is just a backup route. Feasible successor routes are not used to forward traffic, only successor routes are. It is not necessary to have a backup route. If the successor route disappears with no feasible successor, then it triggers a recalculation and reconvergence for that route (queries sent to neighbors), and it may be possible that there is no other route to that destination, causing the route to be dropped.